# Identifying object in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to identify the table . My xpath fails in identifying it. There is no id or name.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/1067814.html

Comment: Which table are you trying to identify? The scoretable?

Comment: can you add the `html` here?

Comment: Yes the score table

Comment: Batsmen R B 4s 6s SR This bowler
Dilhan Cooray (rhb) 33 57 2 1 57.89 5 (8b)
Yashodha Lanka (rhb) 29 30 4 0 96.66 0 (0b) 
Mat Runs HS Ave
63 2439 106* 25.67
35 1803 171 32.19
Bowlers O M R W Econ 0s 4s 6s
Tillakaratne Sampath (ob) 15.0 4 29 1 1.93 69 1 0
Andy Solomons (rfm) 6.0 2 16 0 2.66 26 2 0 
Mat Wkts BBI Ave
106 192 5/38 30.31
57 87 4/17 31.24

Comment: @shahulha, Please update your html in question itself. In comment it seems you have paste the table data not actually table structure. Also mention how you are trying to locate

Comment: @shahulha, try `driver.findElement(By.className("score-table"));`

Comment: @Andersson, it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
List<WebElement> scoreTable=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#summary > div:nth-child(3) > div")).findElements(By.className("score-table"));
        for (WebElement table : scoreTable) {
            List<WebElement> rows=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            for (WebElement row : rows) {
                System.out.println(row.getText());
            }
        }
```